# Google Maps SDK on older iOS Versions

Tags: ios, google-maps, sdk, version, cocoapods

I'm very new to maps and I've been following this Google Maps tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start).

My app is running perfectly on iOS 8 but crashes on older versions.

I'm pretty sure this problem is with the following line in my Podfile.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'  <-- this line
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

Is it just a case of changing this platform to 7.0 if I want it to run on older versions of iOS?

This will involve me having to remove the SDKs and start from scratch, right?

Is there a way to fix this issue, without having to re-install all these SDKs... that was a lot of effort for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating it wont be a huge task. all you have to do is use 7.0 instead of 8.1 OR remove that line altogether...

Save your podfile and just run the following command in your terminal..

```
pod update
```

And you are done...

All the best.